# select all filterd values in angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a select all select all to my angular material table, and I need, that, when clicking select all only the elements filtered are selected and pushed to the selectedDevices array. I'm trying to filter by myself the values of the dataSource according to the value of my ngModel='valueToFilter'. I was trying to filter only by the value of one key but I need to filter by all the key values. This is what I'm trying

My html

```
  <mat-form-field class="filterField">
              <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter" 
             [(ngModel)]='valueToFilter'>
            </mat-form-field>

 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class=" mat-elevation-z8"
              (matSortChange)="storeSort($event)" fxFlex="100">

<ng-container matColumnDef="checkbox">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                  <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null;"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                    
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected() && masterIndeterminate" [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()"
                    >
                  </mat-checkbox>
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                  <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(element) : null; 
                    markAsSelected(element)"
                    [checked]="isDevicSelected(element._id)" [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(element)"
                    [(ngModel)]="checkboxes[element._id]" (ngModelChange)="onSelectedChange(element._id)">
                  </mat-checkbox>
                </td>
              </ng-container>
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
              <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;">
              </tr>
            </table>
```

my ts  mastertoggle that controls de select all deselect all

```
 masterToggle(): void {
        if (this.isAllSelected()) {
            this.deselectDevices();
            this.selection.clear();
        } else if (!this.isAllSelected()) {
            if( this.valueToFilter.trim().toLowerCase() !== '' ) {
               const rows = this.dataSource.data.filter(r => r.tagProvisioned.trim().toLowerCase());  // here I want to filer the values of my dataSource  according to the value of the input in order to tag as selected



            }
            this.selectDevices();
            this.dataSource.data.forEach((row) =>
            this.selection.select(row));
          
    }
```

my service where I the selectdevices() method maps all the devices and push the id

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ProvisionedService {
    onSelectedDevicesChanged: BehaviorSubject<any>;
}

 constructor(
       
    ) {
        this.onSelectedDevicesChanged = new BehaviorSubject([]);
        
    }

 public selectDevices(filterParameter?, filterValue?): void {
        this.selectedDevices = [];
        // If there is no filter, select all contacts
        if (
            filterParameter === undefined ||
            filterValue === undefined
        ) {
            this.selectedDevices = [];
            this.devices.map((device) => {
                this.selectedDevices.push(device._id);
            });
        }
        this.onSelectedDevicesChanged.next(this.selectedDevices);
      
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`DataSource` has a property called `filteredData` which is only the array of the filtered results.

You can use `this.dataSource.filteredData` instead of `this.dataSource.data`

```
masterToggle() {
    
  this.isAllSelected() ?
  this.selection.clear() :
  this.dataSource.filteredData.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
}
```

Comment: When this solution applied, don't forget to also adapt `isAllSelected()`:
    ```
isAllSelected() {
        const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
        const numRows = this.dataSource.filteredData.length;
        return numSelected === numRows;
      }
```